# Propagating managed context to tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode7, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Hello I am following a tutorial by **raywenderlich - Core data by tutorials v 2.0**

I am trying to combine my app with the tutorial examples there.

I want to implement this part: 
[propagating managed context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETdgv.png) to my current app

My current app has a `UINavigationController` and it is connected to `UITableViewController` which uses custom class name `PatientTableViewController.swift`

I am trying to add  `"var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext!"` to my `PatientTableViewController.swift` file

So what should be the implementation to my "func application" method in appDelegate.swift:

My current method looks like this :

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let viewController = window!.rootViewController as! PatientTableViewController

        viewController.managedContext = managedObjectContext

         return true
}
```

I don't get any error but when i run the app i get 'Thread 1 signal SIGABRT'

for line `"let viewController = window!.rootViewController as! PatientTableViewController"`

Any help would be appriciated !!!

Comment: it works properly in my test project

Answer (score 0):

Create new Single view based project with CoreData marked and copy it's AppDelegate to yours.

Or add this to your AppDelegate file after `applicationWillTerminate`:

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
        // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.companyName.yourProjectName" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
        let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count-1]
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("yourProjectName", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
    }()

    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        // Create the coordinator and store
        let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        do {
            try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
        } catch {
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
            let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        return coordinator
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and import `CoreData`

Comment: thank you for your answer but i need the implementation of the function in appdelegate : func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {}

Comment: do u follow this tutorial? http://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial

Comment: so why dont u just replace `let viewController =
      window!.rootViewController as! ViewController` to `let viewController =
      window!.rootViewController as! TableViewController`?

Comment: I tried but i am getting error : Cannot assign value of type 'NSManagedObjectContext' to type 'NSManagedObjectContext!.Type' (aka 'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<NSManagedObjectContext>.Type')

Comment: My Code looks like : func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        let viewController = window!.rootViewController as! PatientTableViewController?
        
            viewController?.managedContext = managedObjectContext
        
             return true
    }

Comment: viewController?.managedContext = managedObjectContext line getting the error